# Datasource for multitenant application

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, datasource, multi-tenant

I am developing a multitenant application based on Hibernat 4.
I use separate database solution. 
I use Mysql as a database provider.
For each new tenant i add a  new database to mysql.
I would like to add a new tenant to my application without restarting the appserver.
I use DriverManagerDataSource to create a new datasource for each tenant, but this class not intended to use in production? Which class should i use?
I was thinking to add the datasource to appserver and use JNDIdatasource, but the problem is i need to restart the appserver for each new tenant. Is there any way to add datasource without restarting the appserver?

Comment: Maybe this will help you: http://blog.springsource.org/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing/

Comment: It is generally not a good design to create a database for each new user / tenant etc. You might want to think about using a single database with partitioning: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-overview.html

Answer (score 1):

To give you a direct answer to your question, you could expose your application context via JMX and programatically modify it. The problem with this is that changes will be transient, i.e. they won't be persisted if you restart your server.

Another option is to programatically modify the underlying xml files (assuming you are using xml) and call [refresh()](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/context/ConfigurableApplicationContext.html#refresh%28%29) on the application context. For example you could create a velocity template with placeholders for the datasources:

```
<beans>
...
#foreach ( $datasource in $datasources )
  $datasource
#end
...
</beans>
```

You would then pass a list of all your required datasources to velocity which would then generate an updated datasource-context.xml

**But as other users have pointed out this is really not a good idea, better to go with partitioning or another approach**